# Is there any built in utility to check for "null" String instead of null?

Tags: java, string, null, equals

I am extracting a variable value from Apache Avro `GenericRecord` so my String variable value is coming as "null" instead of null.

```
GenericRecord payload = decoder.decode(record.value());
String userid = String.valueOf(payload.get("userId"));
// here userid is null string as "null"
System.out.println(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(userid));
```

And because of that "null" string, my `sysout` prints out as false. How can I check this so that it prints out as "true" bcoz string was a null string. Is there any built in utitilty which does that or I have to write my own ".equals" check?

Comment: You need to fix the root cause. "null" is a valid string, make sure that you get `null` and not `"null"` from the GenericRecord. [Mr Null](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/) will thank you.

Comment: I doubt that is possible bcoz that's how Avro schema is defined I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably generate the `"null"` String by yourself with the `String.valueOf(...)` method. From the JavaDoc of [`String#valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns:
>       if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

Thus, I suggest to use the following code:

```
    GenericRecord payload = decoder.decode(record.value());
    boolean isNull = payload.get("userId") == null;
    if (!isNull) {
        String userid = payload.get("userId").toString();
    }
```

This prevents the problem of comparing with the `"null"` String by not generating it.

Comment: Yes you are right. It was coming from `String.valueOf`

Answer (score 1):

`"null"` is a plain string type, just use the API of `String` type: `.equals("null")` is ok.